# Why is the table view scrolling lagging?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I implemented a table view, but the scrolling is lagging. Why is it lagging? I am reusing the cell, but it is still lagging. When I scroll, the memory spikes and comes back to normal when the scrolling stops. If it is of any use, I implemented a collectionview inside of the table view cell.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: BoxCell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BoxCell

    cell.pic.image = pic[indexPath.row].circle


    return cell
}

extension UIImage {
var circle: UIImage? {
    let square = CGSize(width: min(size.width, size.height), height: min(size.width, size.height))
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: square))
    imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    imageView.image = self
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = square.width/2
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
    imageView.layer.renderInContext(context)
    let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return result
}

}
```

Comment: what is in the collection view that is in each cell? if its loading images or something, those need to be loaded asynchronously

Comment: It's just loading text which is imported from parse

Comment: How are you loading that text?

Comment: Whatever is in the above method is in the BoxCell plus the collection view, and no I am not using shadows

Comment: `query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`

Comment: It's lagging because you're loading everything at the same time and needs more time to find the data. 

Instead, you can create a new queue to load it in parallel and when it's done go back to the main one.

I just used it on this simple project loading images with the flickr API:
 https://gitlab.com/vicrius/flickrVisualizer

Comment: see if wrapping that if statement with the image loading in a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { })` improves anything, image loading is a relatively slow task (you may need to set the image to a pre-loaded image first while the real image loads, or show some kind of loading indicator, or just make the image blank, otherwise the recycled cells last image will show for a short time)

Comment: @Fonix, it doesn't change

Comment: slower in what way, that seems impossible

Comment: it should be your collectionView that makes the main uitableview lagged. Try first with hard code in your collectionview. I don't think that loading an image from the resources of application is the reason for lagging.

Comment: @HoaParis, doesn't seem like it, I hardcoded the value, and it still lags.

Comment: i would comment out different sections of your code and see when/if there is no more lag so you can pin-point where this lag is coming from, we can only speculate here

Comment: @Fonix seems like the best route to go.

Comment: I updated my code to show which line was causing the problem

Comment: try put a dispatch_async like i mentioned above around `cell.pic.image = pic[indexPath.row].circle`... the operations you are doing inside that circle method are relatively expensive (especially the renderInContext part + a few other lines around it, which is basically make a completely new copy of the image)

Answer (score 0):

How big are your images?  If they are big images table will slowdown. I have recently encountered with that problem. Using smaller images make it faster again.

Comment: The images are small, less than 1mb

Comment: around 1mb is fairly big. Try the tableview without loading images maybe ?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the comment. I meant just try the table without loading images with just only text. If it gets faster you may try reducing size and using thumbnails for the tableview.

Comment: Tried that, still lags.

Comment: I updated my code to show which line was causing the problem

Comment: So it is related either with image or the mask you applied. You should eliminate that too. Try without the circle. Try applying mask to imageview but do not load the images.  See what is causing the problem.

Comment: I tried that and it works smoothly with the mask and no image so it's definitely the image, but I'm sure it's not the size, it's not that big.

Comment: It is actually big. You should use the images as small as possible. I would two versions if the image one small for the tableview (thumbnail) and one for the detail view. When you load the detail view show the bigger image.

Comment: What would be considered big in this case, I just checked these photos I am importing are about 20-40 kb

Comment: When you said less than 1 mb I thought it was around 1mb.  20-40kb should not be a problem. Maybe you can try the limit the size of the array and try again. I don't know how big the array is but I am just guessing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114198/discussion-between-kivannc-and-manatee).

Answer (score 0):

A lot is happening in this cell maybe tone down its resources. For example the collection view is being reloaded every time you are scrolling through the table view. "cell.collectionview.reloadData()".  Maybe take the contents of the cell and load it once in an Awake From Nib custom cell instead of calling all these operators, image and coordinates for every cell each time you are scrolling through your table view.  The memory is spiking because you are also reloading your collection view, no matter how large it is, every time you are scrolling.  Everything is being handled on the main thread as well.  Maybe move some image layout code to a background thread for a smoother scrolling action.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    //Image work here (including image if statement)
})
```

Ideally move the image loading to awake from nib so it load once.

Comment: I updated my code to show which line was causing the problem

Comment: Which line was it?